# Error Parsing Json Data

Tags: android, json

I can fetch data from the server and even log the results to logcat but when I try to parse the data using JsonParser, I get an IOException error as follows:

```
09-17 17:18:16.989  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: closed
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:164)
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1263)
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1309)
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:538)
09-17 17:18:16.995  26081-26123/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:414)
```

This is how i fetch the data:

```
private JsonReader getJsonData(String link) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        JsonReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Snackbar.make(layout, Constants.SERVER_ERROR, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (is != null) {
                reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return reader;
    }

    private ArrayList<Track> readBegin(JsonReader reader) {
        ArrayList<Track> items = new ArrayList<>();

        try {

            reader.setLenient(true);
//            JsonToken token = reader.peek();
//            //Log.e("Next", token.toString());

            reader.beginObject();

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                if (reader.nextName().equals(TRACKS)) {

                    reader.beginObject();

                    while (reader.hasNext()) {
                        switch (reader.nextName()) {
                            case TRACK:
                                reader.beginArray();

                                while (reader.hasNext()) {
                                    items.add(parseData(reader));
                                }

                                reader.endArray();
                                break;
                            default:
                                reader.skipValue();
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    reader.endObject();
                }
            }

            reader.endObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return items;
    }

    private Track parseData(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        String title = null;
        String artist = null;
        String duration = null;
        String albumArt = null;

        jsonReader.beginObject();

        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
            switch (jsonReader.nextName()) {
                case NAME:
                    title = jsonReader.nextString();
                    break;
                case DURATION:
                    duration = jsonReader.nextString();
                    break;
                case ARTIST:
                    JsonToken peek = jsonReader.peek();
                    if (peek != JsonToken.NULL) {
                        jsonReader.beginObject();

                        while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                            switch (jsonReader.nextName()) {
                                case NAME:
                                    artist = jsonReader.nextString();
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    jsonReader.skipValue();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        jsonReader.endObject();
                    }
                    break;
                case IMAGE:
                    albumArt = getImage(jsonReader);
                    break;
                default:
                    jsonReader.skipValue();
                    break;
            }
        }

        jsonReader.endObject();

        if (title != null && duration != null && artist != null) {
            if (albumArt == null) {
                albumArt = "R.color.image_placeholder";
            }

            return new Track(title, artist, duration, albumArt);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The code was working fine up until the last few days. I have tried to rewrite the method of fetching but i concluded that that wasnt the issue. Several issues raised online pointed to the the stream closing before parsing ended but I havent found a way of solving the issue.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Conside using google's gson: https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Usually in such situations the issue hiding on a server) And always you think you have some problem in working code)

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was the

```
finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

clause which closed the connection before the reader could parse the data. Removing that code and adding it after the reading is complete solved the problem.